# Use Font Awesome font in bookmarks

Tags: xetex, bookmarks, fontawesome

Is it possible to use a Font Awesome character(s) in a bookmark?

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\section{\faWrench First section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

When I run this through xelatex I get the following error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/FontAwesome(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/FontAwesome(0)/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

This is what I get for the PDF output:

[image: PDF output]

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bookmark

The PDF bookmarks can be encoded in PDFDocEncoding (default, 8bit) or Unicode (UTF-16BE with BOM). Option `pdfencoding=auto` or `unicode` are needed to enable Unicode bookmarks:

```
\usepackge[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
```

The wrench symbol 🔧 is available in Unicode as U+1F527. Then the symbol
can be supported in the bookmarks via the generic `\unichar` with expects the Unicode code point number. In `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` macros can be redefined, when bookmarks are processed:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faWrench{\unichar{"1F527}}%
}
```

Alternatively, `\texorpdfstring` can be used in the section title.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faWrench{\unichar{"1F527}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{\faWrench First section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result bookmark]

### Font warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/FontAwesome(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/FontAwesome(0)/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

This means, that the symbol font is not available as bold font. Instead the symbols are taken from the normal font. Therefore you can ignore the warning here.

Comment: This work-around **is** a fix, but I am not ready to mark it as solved yet.  I am investigating making a "bold" version of Font Awesome so I can have the same characters in both places.

Comment: @Gene Then make feature requests to the maintainer of package `fontawesome` to support these symbols in bookmarks, which are available in Unicode, and to add a bold version of the font.

Comment: Thank you - but before I do that I try to have a working solution and we are not there yet.  I made a "bold" version of `Font Awesome` and modified the character "faWrench".  In the document I placed a "faWrench" at the beginning of the lipsum.  When I run xelatex now I get `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing \`\char\' on input line 10.` When I look at the PDF the bookmark has not changed(per the "warning"), the new bold character is in title and normal character is in the lipsum.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Gene PDF viewers do not have TeX engines to typeset the bookmarks. Either use `\texorpdfstring{...}{\unichar{"1F527}}` in your text or redefine the macro as shown in my answer, if the symbol is set by a macro like `\faWrench`.

Comment: Thank you for helping.  I tried creating a new font just with the letter "d" but the glyph instead of a letter, so I was in the normal ASCII range.  The actual letter "d" was used in the bookmark while the glyph was used in the title and body - that's frustrating.  I am assuming that is a PDF limitation?

Comment: @Gene Bookmark strings are plain text strings without any further formatting. You can only make the whole string bold and/or italics, see the documentation of package `bookmark`. The font of the bookmark depends on the font, the PDF viewer uses for the bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error: just a warning. It is just telling you it can't find bold so is using the regular weight instead. This is nothing to worry about unless you were expecting it to find a bold weight of a font.

The bookmarks are displayed in a font determined by your PDF viewer - not the document - as far as I know. Notice that the font of the text does not match the font of the section header in the document in your example, either - it is not just the symbol which is different.

Comment: So is it fixable?  I would like to have the character in the bookmark.  Or do I need to reachout to the makers of the font and have them encode the characters as bold as well?

Comment: @Gene I see you got an expert answer in the meantime ;).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a reason not to do this, but I just suppressed the warning by pointing the reference to that font shape to what it converts it to:

```
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{FontAwesome(0)}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * FontAwesome(0)/m/n}{}
```