# Bookmark showing a box for character

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, bookmarks

The following works on the computer that generated it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily\Segoe{Segoe UI Symbol}

\def\SegoeWrench{\Segoe{\unichar{"1F527}}}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faWrench{\SegoeWrench}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{\faWrench First section}
\faWrench\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

However when I take the PDF to another machine the Wrench does not show in the bookmark.  One thing I have noticed is that Segoe UI Symbol font is not embedded.

I am using xelatex - I am not using Adobe Acrobat Distiller - in updmap.cfg pdftexDownloadBase14 is true.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The bookmarks don't use the text font, but rely on the OS for displaying characters. It's very possible that an OS can show U+1F527, but another one can't.

Comment: It seems to be Adobe Acrobat.  On the machine that is producing the PDF is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (latest) but on the other machine it is Adobe Acrobat Pro X.

Answer (score 1):

The bookmark text for `\faWrench` contains a font command `\Segoe` (BTW, the command is a font switch command, *not* a macro with an argument). Font switch commands are **NOT** allowed inside bookmarks. Or does a PDF viewer exists, which can make use of a LaTeX font switch command?

Instead of

```
\newfontfamily\Segoe{segoeui.ttf}
\def\SegoeWrench{\Segoe{\unichar{"1F527}}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faWrench{\SegoeWrench}%
}
```

`\faWrench` is defined for the bookmarks the following way, as already provided in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261584/16967) of mine:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\faWrench{\unichar{"1F527}}%
}
```

Then it depends on the PDF viewer, which font is uses for the bookmarks, and if it uses a font, which contains this Unicode symbol.

But there is *nothing* that can be done at TeX or PDF level. Bookmark strings are plain text strings without any markup.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I am still learning and appreciate the patience.  Since "Wrench" is part of Segoe UI Symbol and Symbola I was trying to get the font embedded.  I commented above that I think this might be an Adobe Acrobat issue.